# Why does collider adjustment in a shielded triplet tend to cause independence?

Tags: r, causality, structural-equation-modeling, mutual-information, dag

I created a causal model in which $X$ causes $Y$ and $Z$, and $Y$ causes $Z$ in the following way:

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 10000

X <- purrr::rbernoulli(N)
Y <- X + purrr::rbernoulli(N)
Z <- 2*X + 3*Y + purrr::rbernoulli(N)
```

I created it this way so that the variables are discrete. That's it. The equivalent DAG would be the one below:

[image]

People working with causal inference are probably more used to unshielded triplets, in which case we would have no edge between $X$ and $Y$ and therefore a v-structure. In this hypothetical situation, $X$ and $Y$ are independent but become [spuriously] dependent when conditioning on $Z$, a collider.

However, going back to the diagram I showed, there is direct association between $X$ and $Y$ and if we adjust on $Z$, we open a blocked path, in the sense that we add some spurious dependence between $X$ and $Y$ through $Z$. What's driving me nuts is that the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ not only is larger than $X$ and $Y$ conditioned by $Z$, but the latter is $0$! That is,

$I(X;Y) > I(X;Y|Z) = 0$. In R:

```
infotheo::condinformation(X,Y)
infotheo::condinformation(X,Y,Z)
```

I tried changing the equations for $Y$ and $Z$ and yet, the zero is always there (almost always, check the end of the question) for $I(X;Y|Z)$, whenever it's a shielded triplet. Even if I do it with continuous variables and normal distributions for the noise, I still find the same thing.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 10000

X <- rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)
Y <- X + rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)
Z <- X + Y + rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)

miic::discretizeMutual(X,Y, plot=FALSE)$info
miic::discretizeMutual(X,Y, matrix_u=matrix(Z), plot=FALSE)$info
```

But then, if I change a bit the structural equation for $Z$, I get something different from zero.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 10000

X <- rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)
Y <- X + rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)
Z <- 2*X + 3*Y + rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)

miic::discretizeMutual(X,Y, plot=FALSE)$info
miic::discretizeMutual(X,Y, matrix_u=matrix(Z), plot=FALSE)$info
```

I also get a value different from zero if I make the distribution of the noise in $Z$ explicitly different from the noise in $X$ and $Y$.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 10000

X <- rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)
Y <- X + rnorm(N, mean=10, sd=2)
Z <- X + Y + rnorm(N, mean=100, sd=10)

miic::discretizeMutual(X,Y, plot=FALSE)$info
miic::discretizeMutual(X,Y, matrix_u=matrix(Z), plot=FALSE)$info
```

I don't understand what's happening here. I tried to draw a few diagrams, see what paths would be blocked or opened, what would happen with correlation between the noises, but I can't think of a way that adjusting for the collider $Z$ would make $X$ and $Y$ independent. A hypothesis would be some sort of cancelling of effects between the two paths, but I changed the equations in ways that I didn't expect it to happen and still... The $0$ is there.

Could you please explain to me what's happening here? Both analytically, if possible, and intuitively. By intuitively, I'm referring to the intuitive explanations for the unshielded triplets. Adjusting for $B$ in $A \rightarrow B \leftarrow C$ makes A and C dependent. Adjusting for $B$ in $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ or $A \leftarrow B \rightarrow C$ make $A$ and $B$ independent. Something along these lines :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a formal example of linear causal model that share your DAG.
[Which OLS assumptions are colliders violating?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525369/which-ols-assumptions-are-colliders-violating/525435#525435)

I consider (there and here) the case where all noises are independent each others. Moreover now I consider here the particular case where noises are standard Normal. Moreover, like in your example, I start considering all three causal parameters equal to $1$.

As showed in my example (in the link) the causal coefficient/effect of $X$ on $Y$ can be consistently estimated from the regression of $Y$ on $X$. No controls are needed, indeed if we add a collider ($Z$) as control the regression coefficient of $X$ is no more a consistent estimator of the causal coefficient of $X$ on $Y$; worse, it do not represent any causal parameter of SCM. It is a useless regression coefficient.

Actually under the just suggested parametrization, the useless regression coefficient converge precisely to $0$; from normality assumption we can said that $X$ and $Y$ are independent conditioned on $Z$.

Now you said that

> I tried changing the equations for $Y$ and $Z$ and yet, the zero is always
> there (almost always, check the end of the question) for $I(X;Y|Z)$,
> whenever it's a shielded triplet. Even if I do it with continuous
> variables and normal distributions for the noise, I still find the
> same thing. ...
> But then, if I change a bit the structural equation for $Z$, I get something different from zero. ...
> A hypothesis would be some sort of cancelling of effects between the two paths, but I changed the equations in ways that I didn't expect it to happen and still... The 0 is there.

This do not seems me completely clear and true. Indeed from my example if the causal parameter in the structural equation for $Y$ is different from $1$ the useless regression coefficient become different from zero. For example if the causal parameter in that structural equation is $2$ the conditional independence claimed do not hold. Indeed the useless regression coefficient converrge to $0,5$

Moreover following the alternative parameterization that you suggest ($2$ and $3$ as causal parameters in structural equation for $Z$ and retain $1$ in the equation for $Y$) the useless regression coefficient converge to $-0,5$.

In general, different values of causal parameters can produce null or positive or negative value for the useless regression coefficient. Moreover even the distribution of structural errors matters.

Finally

> Why does collider adjustment in a shielded triplet tend to cause
> independence?

the independence you claimed can happen in particular cases (parameters combinations) but in general it do not hold. Indeed the general message is that control for collider is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you, @markowitz!

Answer (score 1):

This is called colliding bias, also called [Berkson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkson%27s_paradox), if the relationship between X and Y conditions on Z. Conditioning on Z will induce negative association between X and Y, so if X affects Y positively, then this positive causation will be reduced, even to 0, as you showed.

Comment: Indeed, by replacing X with -X in the structural equations, things worked out according to your reasoning. Thanks, Jinghong.

Comment: My pleasure @mribeirodantas